# How do I redirect users that are not on my ip to a page rather than just an apache error page?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to take my website down for an hour while I make changes and I have used

```
order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from my.ip.add.ress
```

How do I redirect users that are not on my ip to a page rather than just given an bog standard apache error page? I want something prettier.

Comment: webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Comment: posted it on there but i thought here would have been of more benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /misc/403page.html
```

Then create a file called 403page.html in /misc (or whatever) and you're good to go.  Make sure that /misc is outside of the document root for the site in question.

[EDIT AllowOverride will need to be set to FileInfo for this to work]

Comment: is there no way to do this from the root? i only have access to the root of the site :S

Comment: on reflection it looks like it can be in the document root - see here: http://www.codestyle.org/sitemanager/apache/errors-403.shtml